# How to Close modal window and refresh parent window in salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

My Requirement is when we click on edit button open child visualforce page as modal window when we save that record close that modal window and refrsh parent page.

Answer (score 0):

```
function closeAndRefresh(){
  opener.location.reload(); // or opener.location.href = opener.location.href;
  window.close(); // or self.close();
}
```

This will work for you.